# Android: Unicode character not displayed in some devices

Tags: android, unicode

I try to display Georgian Lari symbol to textView but in some devices it fails

in some devices it looks like this:

[image: Here is How it looks]

it should look like this:

[image: it should look like this]

here's my code. i tried to both in activity.class and layout files:

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="4 \u20BE"/>
```

in MainActivity

```
priceTextView.setText(price + " \u20BE");
```

I know that old devices don't have this symbol, but is there anyway that i could fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may attach font file to Your project that contains required by You symbols.

```
priceTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/customFont.otf"));
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked. But, is there any way that i could make text bold and use that font at the same time?

Comment: Ok, i found solution. added another typeface in constructor priceTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/customFont.otf"),,Typeface.BOLD)